# Angular http requests not getting sent to server

Tags: angular, httprequest

I have an Angular 6 app and this is my http request:

```
updatePending(ids: Array<number>): Observable<boolean> {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(ids));
    return this.http.post<boolean>(this.TRANSACTION_URL, { type: 'Update', ids: ids 
  });
}
```

This `updatePending` method is run when a button is clicked. It successfully gets here and runs the `console.log`. I can see my `ids` array being printed to the console. When it tried to run the post request, the request doesn't go through. I have the Network tab open in the Chrome dev tools and when I click the button to run this code, there is no new entry.

There are no errors at all on the client side, just nothing happens and no request is sent to the server. I have several other post requests in my app, all structured the same way, but nothing is working for this particular one.

I have checked `this.TRANSACTION_URL` and it is the correct URL.

Comment: You need to subscribe to your observable. Observables are lazy, and don't do anything until they have a subscriber

Comment: As I say, Observables are lazy. The Observable will not actually make the request until it has a subscriber,

Comment: Sorry I skimmed through that @user184994 and didn't read it fully, I understand now thank you